# build bundle/ apk disabled in android studio for flutter project

Tags: flutter, apk

In build bulidbundle/apk was disable in android studio.unable to generate the apk file in android studio for flutter application.[image]

Comment: run flutter build apk --release

Comment: open your android project (android folder) in android studio, then you can see bulidbundle/apk then you can see these options are enabled

Answer (score 3):

Push on main directory in project explorer

Answer (score 0):

Please try to restart the android studio and then Rebuild Project. 
If in case this also not helped, Then Please update your Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved your all files before the build. This will severely happen when you make changes to the multiple files in which you forget to save some of the files.

So, GOTO **File => Save All** option. Hope this will fix your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the top-level item in the project folder, then check if the  menu appears as below:
Menu showing build apk option

[image: Menu showing build apk option]